# Update by id function is not working in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to NodeJS and trying to build a backend API for a car rental agency. I have wrote a code to update, view and delete the records by id stored in MongoDB but it only prints the content of index page and does not update, retrieve or perform deletion. I checked the route mapping in the routes.js but still don't know what is causing this bug. Is there any problem with the syntax? I'm using node version 12.18.3.

Here is my code,

index.js

```
let express = require('express');

let app = express();

let mongoose = require('mongoose');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8081

let bodyparser = require('body-parser');

const { urlencoded } = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded(
    {
       extended: true 
    }))

app.use(bodyparser.json());

var apiRoutes = require('./routes');
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);


const dbPath = "mongodb://localhost/carrentalagencypractice"
const options = {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true}
const mongo = mongoose.connect(dbPath,options)

mongo.then(()=>{
    console.log('Connected to mongodb')
} ,error=> {console.log(error,'error')})


app.use('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Welcome to Car Rental Agency')
});


app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Running on port '+port)
});
```

routes.js

```
let router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.json({
       status: 'API works',
       message: 'Welcome to Car Rental Agency services'
   })
})


var carController = require('./carController')
var userController = require('./userController')

router.route('/car').get(carController.index).post(carController.add)
router.route('/user').get(userController.index).post(userController.add)

router.route('/car/car_id').get(carController.view).patch(carController.update).put(carController.update).delete(carController.delete)
router.route('/user/user_id').get(userController.index).patch(userController.update).put(userController.update).delete(userController.delete)

module.exports = router
```

carModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    brand:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    price:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    capacity:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    }
});


var Car = module.exports = mongoose.model('car',carSchema);

module.exports.get = function(callback, limit){
    Car.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

userModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    phone:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    address:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})


var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)

module.exports.get = function(callback, limit){
    User.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

userController.js

```
User = require("./userModel");


exports.index = function(req, res){
    User.get(function(err, user){
    if(err)
    res.send(err)

    res.json({
        status: "Got all user details successfully",
        message: user
    })
})
}

exports.add = function(req, res){
User.add(function(err, user){
    var user = new User()

    if(err)
    res.send(err)

    user.name = req.body.name ? req.body.name : user.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.address = req.body.address;
    user.phone = req.body.phone;

    res.json({
        status: "User details are successfully added",
        message: user
    })
})
}


exports.view = function(req, res){
    User.findByID(req.params.user_id, function(err, user){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)

        res.json({
            status: "Successfully retreived user details",
            message: user
        })
    })
}

exports.update = function(req, res){
    User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)

        user.name = req.body.name? req.body.name: user.name;
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.address = req.body.address;
        user.phone = req.body.phone;

        user.save(function(req, res){
            if(err)
            res.send(err)
    
            res.json({
                status: "User details updated successfully",
                message: user
            })
        })
    }
    )
}


exports.delete = function(req, res){
    User.deleteOne(req.params.user_id, function(err, user){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)
        
        res.json({
            status: "success",
            message: "The user account has been deleted"
        })
    })
}
```

carController.js

```
Car = require('./carModel');


exports.index = function(req, res){
                    
    Car.get(function(err, car){
        if(err)
        res.json({
            status: "error",
            message: err
        })

        res.json({
            status: "successfull",
            message: "Car details succesfully retreived",
            data: car
        })
    });
}


exports.add = function(req, res){
    var car = new Car();
    car.name = res.body.name ? req.body.name : car.name;
    car.brand = res.body.brand;
    car.price = res.body.price;
    car.capacity = res.body.capacity;


    car.save(function(err){
        if(err)
        res.json(err);
        console.log

        res.json({
            status: "successfull",
            message: "Successfully add new car details"
        })

    })

}


exports.view = function(req, res){
    Car.findById(req.params.car_id, function(err, car){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)

        res.json({
            status: "Car details",
            message: car
        })
    })

}


exports.update = function(req, res){
    Car.findById(req.params.car_id, function(err, car){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)

        car.name = req.body.name? req.body.name: car.name;
        car.price = req.body.price;
        car.brand = req.body.brand;
        car.capacity = req.body.capacity;

        car.save(function(err){

            if(err)
            res.send(err)

            res.json({
                status:"Car details updated successfully",
                message: car
            })

        })
    })
}


exports.delete = function(req, res){
    Car.deleteOne({
        _id: car_id
    }, function(err, contact){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)

        res.json({
            status: "success",
            message:"Car ad deleted"
        })
    }
    )
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically grab ids on routes, rather than:

```js
router.route('/car/car_id').get(carController.view).patch(carController.update).put(carController.update).delete(carController.delete)
router.route('/user/user_id').get(userController.index).patch(userController.update).put(userController.update).delete(userController.delete)
```

Use:

```js
router.route('/car/:car_id').get(carController.view).patch(carController.update).put(carController.update).delete(carController.delete)
router.route('/user/:user_id').get(userController.index).patch(userController.update).put(userController.update).delete(userController.delete)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! so if we don't put : before it does it search for the definition in the code?

Comment: When using ":" you indicate that that value is dynamic, instead of a fixed value.